# core dumped when creating a unique ptr with type cast

Tags: c++

I have a function called `set` which accepts `unique_ptr<Base>`, an object of type `Base` called `base`, I'm trying to call function `set` like this in a function called `save` like this:

```
void AClass::save(){
    ......
    Base base = .....;
    someobj.set(std::make_unique<Derived>(*(Derived*)&base)));
    ......
}
```

But when I run the code, I got core dumped, in the above code, I'm dereferencing a casted pointer, and then create a unique ptr, in the code below, I know why core dumped happens, but why same thing also happens in the above case?

```
void AClass::save(){
    ......
    Base base = .....;
    someobj.set(std::make_unique<Base>(&base)));
    ......
}
```

Comment: Can you give us enough code to reproduce the problem? It matters what the constructors and destructors of `Base` do. It matters what type `set` takes. And so on.

Comment: What? Am I reading it right? You are taking an address of a local variable of type `Base` and then casting it to `Derived*` even though it's not actually an instance of that type?

Comment: Quite apart from using the cast to lie to the compiler, you're creating a `unique_ptr` to a local variable. The subsequent `delete` is going to be bad. What are you actually trying to achieve here?